# Retrieving values from table 2 using table 1

Tags: sql, join, average

I have two tables dept and work; values are like this

```
INSERT INTO DEPT(DEPTID, DEPTNAME) VALUES
        ( 1, 'DEPT1'),
        (2, 'DEPT2'),
        (3,'DEPT2'),
        (4,'DEPT4'),
        (5,'DEPT4'),
        (6,'DEPT6');

INSERT INTO WORK (WORKID, DEPTID, SAL,CITYID) VALUES
   (  100,1,1000,10),
   (  100,2,2000,10),
   (  200,1,2500,20),
   (  300,3,1000,10),
   (  300,6,3000,10),
   (  300,6,1000,30)
;
```

For the given cityid ( work table), take all deptids for each deptname (from dept table ) and match in work table, if exists display count (count of deptids present in work table) and avgsal else 0 for count and avgsal all dept names in the same order present in dept table. Output should be like this

```
Cityid  deptname count avg-sal
10       dept1    1     1000
10       dept2    2     1500
10       dept4    0      0
10       dept6    1      3000
Grandtotal        3      2333.33
```

I tried thru joins, but didnt work properly

Comment: Where does 2333.33 come from?  And why is the grand total count 3?

Answer (score 0):

You have a very strange department table -- containing duplicates.

In any case, this is a `join` and `group by`:

```
select 10 as cityid, coalesce(d.deptname, 'Total') as name,
       count(w.workid) as cnt,
       avg(sal) as average_salary
from dept d left join
     work w
     on w.deptid = d.deptid and w.cityid = 10
group by grouping sets ((w.cityid, d.deptname) ());
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25f3153d5777caadf6e4c84807aeae6d) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this returns the average salary as the average over the whole population.  This is usually what one wants.  The value is 1750, which looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for reply for that query getting the output like this 
Cityid       deptname     count   avgsal
10     DEPT1      1 1000
NULL DEPT2      0 NULL
10        DEPT2      1 2000
NULL DEPT4      0 NULL
NULL DEPT6      0 NULL

But I need result like this

Cityid  deptname count avg-sal
10       dept1    1     1000
10       dept2    2     1500
10       dept4    0      0
10       dept6    1      3000
Grandtotal        3      2333.33

Comment: Results is like this
10 DEPT4 0 NULL
10 DEPT1 1 1000
10 DEPT2 2 1500
10 DEPT6 1 3000
10 Total 4 1750
Its displaying Null and order is not as per deptname order, grand total is overall sum by count whic is 2333.33

Can we convert this into subquery instead of with ..?
if

Comment: @Velpur . . . The average of averages is probably not want you want.  You probably want the average over all employees -- that at least makes sense.

Comment: yes I need average over all employees. 

and instead of hard coded values since I've table I changed above query into below but its giving different results
with DEPT  as  (select *  from dept)   ,
  WORK as   (select  *  from work)   
  select cityid, coalesce(d.deptname, 'Total') as name,
       count(w.workid) as cnt,
       avg(sal) as average_salary from dept d left join
     work w
     on w.deptid = d.deptid and w.cityid = 10
group by grouping sets ((w.cityid, d.deptname), ())